# How to plot a stacked bar plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I'm trying to do some EDA on a dataset of shop transactions found on kaggle, this one to be precise https://www.kaggle.com/allunia/e-commerce-sales-forecast.

Like all good stores, it offers discounts for bulk orders. I want to see the relationship between a product, quantity and price. Specifically, I want to know how the threshold for discounts is applied across all products within the dataset.

(Its also worth noting that it's possible a product has multiple thresholds, in other words a price for under 10 items, price for 10-19 items and a price for 20+ items.)

---

Here's an example of the data and my attempt at plotting:

```
data = [['10', '20', '30', 
         '20', '20', '40', 
         '30', '20', '10', '40'],
        
        [2.95, 9.95, 4.95, 
         5.55, 5.55, 8.5, 
         3.95, 3.95, 1.55, 7.95],
        
        [5,8,3,
         18,11,6,
         11, 20, 20, 9]]
        
rows = zip(data[0], data[1], data[2])
headers = ['StockCode', 'UnitPrice', 'Quantity']
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)   

pivot_df = df.pivot(index='StockCode', columns='Quantity', values='UnitPrice')
pivot_df.loc[:,list(df['Quantity'])].plot.bar(stacked=True,  figsize=(10,7))
```

---

[Output]:

[image: stacked plot]

---

This isn't what I'm after, I think Unit price (y axis) against stockCode (x axis) with quantity as the layers would show the relations I wantt.

1. My question therefore is how do I get this plot?
2. As a secondary question is there any better way of visualising the
   product, quantity and price relationship.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Do you want `stacked=False` in `plot.bar(...)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang That does look better but I think I would prefer Quantity as 'values' (y axis) and price as the 'columns' . Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Then `columns='UnitPrice', values='Quantity'` in your `pivot` function.

Comment: @QuangHoang As mentioned in the post, I tried that but it produced this error - `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`.